# How to simplify this power equation?

Tags: summation

I need a function such that if *input* is $n$ it *outputs* an $n$-digit number. I need a mathematical function.

For example:

$$\begin{align}\mathrm{ANY}(2) &= 22 \\
\mathrm{ANY}(3) &= 333 \\
\mathrm{ANY}(n) &= nnn\ldots n \quad (n \text{ times})\end{align}$$

I think $\mathrm{ANY}(n)$ is something like:

$$\begin{align}\mathrm{ANY}(2) &= (10^1 + 10^2) * 2 \\  
\mathrm{ANY}(3) &= (10^1 + 10^2 + 10^3) * 3 \\
\mathrm{ANY}(n) &= (10^1 + 10^2 + \ldots + 10^n) * n\end{align}$$

My question is can we further simplify  the equation: $10^1 + 10^2 + \ldots +  10^n$? Or is it not possible?

Additionally, I need just *any $n$-digit* number on *$n$ input*, not necessary like $22$, $333$, $4444$, $\ldots$. In case simplification is not possible then suggest me any other function? I have no much idea if its possible.
Also domain to my $\mathrm{ANY}$ function can be $1$ to $100$.

<sub>I need to solve some problem in computer science.</sub>

Comment: if my question is wrong I can remove it and try to find answer myself.

Comment: what is to happen if $n>9$

Comment: @Maesumi actually I just need any `n` digit number don't bothers if it `11111 11111 1` or `22222 22222 2`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This one gives you only till $n\leq 9$. You could take the geometric series which says that 
$$\sum_{k=0}^n q^k = \frac{q^{n+1}-1}{q-1}$$
which is in your case 
$$\frac{1}{10}\cdot \left( \frac{10^{n+1}-1}{9}-1\right)\cdot n$$
the $-1$ is there because you don't have the naught term.

If you only want an arbitrary $n$ digit number take 
$$10^{n-1}$$
if you want alle the same digit take 
$$\frac{10^n-1}{9} \cdot \text{your favorite digit}$$

To get any number from 10  till 99 with your exact formula take 
$$\frac{1}{100} \cdot \sum_{k=1}^\frac{n}{2} 100^k  \cdot n=\frac{1}{99} \cdot (10^n-1)\cdot n$$ 
for $n$ even and 
$$\frac{1}{10} \cdot \sum_{k=1}^\frac{n-1}{2} 100^k \cdot n + \left\lfloor\frac{n}{10}\right\rfloor=\frac{1}{99} (10^{n}-10)\cdot n +\left\lfloor\frac{n}{10}\right\rfloor$$

Comment: Note that when $n \geq 10$, the number of digits will be off.

Comment: Yes I understood your equation.  Thanks

Comment: BTW what is *naught term* ? yes i confuse you people.

Comment: It is the term for $k=0$ don't know if it is a usual expression

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan updated my solution try again, it gives you the wanted pattern :)

Comment: @RaymondCheng made one for 10 till 100

Comment: @DominicMichaelis thanks ..but  your updated answer have summation and power expression that I want to ignore because of efficiency reason in code.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8121/discussion-between-dominic-michaelis-and-grijesh-chauhan)

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan simplified it

Comment: @DominicMichaelis ,your equation is now simple to understand thanks ..:)

Answer (score 4):

I suppose simpler functions would be $\mathrm{any}(n) = 10^{n-1}$, e.g. outputting $\mathrm{any}(3) = 100$, or $\mathrm{any}(n) = 10^n - 1$, e.g. outputting $\mathrm{any}(3) = 999$.

To get the exact function you specified, you could use the formula for geometric series to obtain $\mathrm{any}(3) = (\frac{10^{n} - 1}{9}) \cdot n$. Note that this does *not* give you an  $n$-digit number for $n \geq 10$.

Comment: thanks :) sorry it was so simple I mean your first solution.

Comment: @FixedPoint: Yes, that formula works, but the formula suggested by the OP leads to $\mathrm{any}(n)=(10^n-1)/9 \cdot n$ (note the extra $n$) which gets an unwanted extra digit once $n \geq 10$.

Answer (score 0):

so if you are okay with

any(1)=1

any(2)=11

any(3)=111

and so on then
$$any(N)=\frac{10^N-1}{9}$$
will work for any number of digits so the domain is all natural numbers. You can get a number with whatever number of digits you need.

Comment: Why the downvote? This any(N) does give you a N digit number for any natural number N. any(20)=11111111111111111111